# iOS: When is tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath: called after deletion/insertion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am implementing the edit mode in UITableViewController. I set some rows to non-editable in method `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`. After deletion/insertion, the method `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` is called in seemingly random number of times. I like to know when is the method `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` called after deletion/insertion. 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a random number of times. That method is called one time for every cell present in table (visually present).

When you delete a cell, the system reloads the table, a cell disappears and possibly other cells appear, and for every cell in memory in table the system calls the method.

You can see that if you log the indexPath.

I hope this helps.